# Angular2 unique input for each row of a table

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an input that is getting created for each row (I am using PrimeNG/datatable).

My problem is that this input is getting the local variable #itsmIncident, so that the value can passed to the "Save" button.  However, with multiple rows, this causes problems, and sometimes picks up the value from a text box in a different row.

```
<p-column field="ITSMIncident" header="ITSM Incident" [sortable]="false" 
    [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [editable]="true" (onEdit)="editITSMIncident($event)">
    <template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
        <input #itsmIncident type="text" pInputText [value]="row[col.field]" />
        <button type="button" pButton (click)="editITSMIncident(row, itsmIncident)">Save</button>
    </template>
</p-column>
```

Comment: Could you explain more about how it picks up the value from a different textbox? Does it always get the value of the textbox in the last row? Does it seem to be random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [(ngModel)] which is the best practise when it comes to two way data binding

```
<p-column field="ITSMIncident" header="ITSM Incident" [sortable]="false" 
    [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [editable]="true" (onEdit)="editITSMIncident($event)">
    <template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
        <input #itsmIncident type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="row[col.field]" />
        <button type="button" pButton (click)="editITSMIncident(row, itsmIncident)">Save</button>
    </template>
</p-column>
```

This should force pass that particular row's data. Let me know if any more help needed